# How to append data to a mysql field? mysql_query showing error

Tags: php, mysql, append, concatenation

I am not able to concatenate values to a mysql column, I am trying to make a rating system and for that purpose I am trying to concatenate the userids of people who have voted so that I can then check that who have voted or not.

My query is:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE data SET rating = '$vote',votecount = '$votecount',voter_id=CONCAT(voter_id,'$userid') WHERE id = '$pic_id'")or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```

Whenever I try to put a comma in between voter_id and $userid, it shows an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` while making sure that php.ini file has display_errors set to 1 and not 0.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to store comma separated lists in a column. Please consider a second table for your votes. Every vote for any picture will be a single row in this table.

Comment: What field type is voter_id? Which data type is $userid?

Comment: voter_id is varchar and userid is int. Also I would like to know that if I get my data appended in a field then how will it be possible to extract a particular value s that I can check if the user has voted or not?